# Why isn't my session variable working for second web page?

Tags: php, html, session, session-cookies, session-variables

I was studying sessions and came up with a problem. On my first page, index.php, I wrote a simple code to start a session, given as follow:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<html>
    <body>
       <?php
        $_SESSION['name'] = 'Daniel';
        echo $_SESSION['name'];
       ?> 

       <ul>
       <li><a href="index.php">index</a></li>
       <li><a href="contact.php">contact</a></li>
       </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Next, I created a file contact.php as follow:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        echo $_SESSION['name'];
    ?>
    This is contact page.
</body>
</html>
```

In contact.php the session variable `$_SESSION['name'];` is not displayed. But in the first file, index.php, the session variable is set and is being displayed.

What's wrong here? Why isn't the session variable in contact.php being displayed?

Comment: Did you check the error logs? Because that code should work

Comment: Your code as shown above should work perfectly fine. Are you using different browsers to check if the session variable is stored across browsers? For example are you opening index.php in one browser and contact.php in another?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, what server are you using? Which PHP version?

Comment: Are cookies enabled in your browser? Or do you have other privacy settings in your browser enabled?

Comment: Start with your browser’s developer tools’ network inspector and see if the cookie gets set and send back correctly in the response/request headers. Enable error reporting on the server.

Comment: This works fine, Probably you have a browser issue try in different browsers.

Comment: I restarted my apache server and the above code worked (I don't know why). Thank You all for your help.